# Upon submission form is not validated

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am trying to implement a form that collects data on a concert venue and stores it on my local postgres database using wtforms and flask-sqlalchemy orm.

I have noticed that my form fails to validate preventing me from adding the new record to my database. Please see the relevant code below

Form model

```
class VenueForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField(
        'name', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    city = StringField(
        'city', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    state = SelectField(
        'state', validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=[
            ('AL', 'AL'),
            ('AK', 'AK'),
            ('AZ', 'AZ'),
            ('AR', 'AR'),
            ('CA', 'CA'),
            ('CO', 'CO'),
            ('CT', 'CT'),
            ('DE', 'DE'),
            ('DC', 'DC'),
            ('FL', 'FL'),
            ('GA', 'GA'),
            ('HI', 'HI'),
            ('ID', 'ID'),
            ('IL', 'IL'),
            ('IN', 'IN'),
            ('IA', 'IA'),
            ('KS', 'KS'),
            ('KY', 'KY'),
            ('LA', 'LA'),
            ('ME', 'ME'),
            ('MT', 'MT'),
            ('NE', 'NE'),
            ('NV', 'NV'),
            ('NH', 'NH'),
            ('NJ', 'NJ'),
            ('NM', 'NM'),
            ('NY', 'NY'),
            ('NC', 'NC'),
            ('ND', 'ND'),
            ('OH', 'OH'),
            ('OK', 'OK'),
            ('OR', 'OR'),
            ('MD', 'MD'),
            ('MA', 'MA'),
            ('MI', 'MI'),
            ('MN', 'MN'),
            ('MS', 'MS'),
            ('MO', 'MO'),
            ('PA', 'PA'),
            ('RI', 'RI'),
            ('SC', 'SC'),
            ('SD', 'SD'),
            ('TN', 'TN'),
            ('TX', 'TX'),
            ('UT', 'UT'),
            ('VT', 'VT'),
            ('VA', 'VA'),
            ('WA', 'WA'),
            ('WV', 'WV'),
            ('WI', 'WI'),
            ('WY', 'WY'),
        ]
    )
    address = StringField(
        'address', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    phone = StringField(
        'phone'
    )
    image_link = StringField(
        'image_link'
    )
    genres = SelectMultipleField(
        # TODO implement enum restriction
        'genres', validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=[
            ('Alternative', 'Alternative'),
            ('Blues', 'Blues'),
            ('Classical', 'Classical'),
            ('Country', 'Country'),
            ('Electronic', 'Electronic'),
            ('Folk', 'Folk'),
            ('Funk', 'Funk'),
            ('Hip-Hop', 'Hip-Hop'),
            ('Heavy Metal', 'Heavy Metal'),
            ('Instrumental', 'Instrumental'),
            ('Jazz', 'Jazz'),
            ('Musical Theatre', 'Musical Theatre'),
            ('Pop', 'Pop'),
            ('Punk', 'Punk'),
            ('R&B', 'R&B'),
            ('Reggae', 'Reggae'),
            ('Rock n Roll', 'Rock n Roll'),
            ('Soul', 'Soul'),
            ('Other', 'Other'),
        ]
    )
    facebook_link = StringField(
        'facebook_link', validators=[URL()]
    )
    website_link = StringField(
        'website_link'
    )

    seeking_talent = BooleanField( 'seeking_talent' )

    seeking_description = StringField(
        'seeking_description'
    )
```

Controller

```
@app.route('/venues/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_venue_submission():
  newForm = VenueForm()

  if newForm.validate_on_submit():
    venue = Venue(
      name = newForm.name.data,
      city = newForm.city.data,
      state = newForm.state.data,
      address =newForm.address.data,
      phone = newForm.phone.data,
      image_link =newForm.image_link.data,
      genres = newForm.genres.data,
      facebook_link = newForm.facebook_link.data,
      seeking_description = newForm.seeking_description.data,
      seeking_talent = newForm.seeking_talent.data,
      website = newForm.website_link.data
    ) 
    db.session.add(venue)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('The Venue ' + newForm.name.data + ' has successfully been listed')
  else:
    db.session.rollback()
    flash('An error occurred. Venue ' + newForm.name.data + ' could not be listed.')
  db.session.close()
  return render_template('pages/home.html')
```

html

```
<form method="post" id="venForm" class="form" action="/venues/create">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}
  {% if form.csrf_token.errors %}
      <div class="warning">You have submitted an invalid CSRF token</div>
  {% endif %}
  <h3 class="form-heading">List a new venue <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" title="Back to homepage"><i class="fa fa-home pull-right"></i></a></h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    {{ form.name(class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label>City & State</label>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.city(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='City', autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{ form.state(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='State', autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    {{ form.address(class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone">Phone</label>
      {{ form.phone(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='xxx-xxx-xxxx', autofocus = true) }}
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="genres">Genres</label>
    <small>Ctrl+Click to select multiple</small>
    {{ form.genres(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='Genres, separated by commas', autofocus = true) }}
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="facebook_link">Facebook Link</label>
      {{ form.facebook_link(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='http://', autofocus = true) }}
   </div>
  
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="image_link">Image Link</label>
      {{ form.image_link(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='http://', autofocus = true) }}
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="website_link">Website Link</label>
        {{ form.website_link(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='http://', autofocus = true) }}
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
         <label for="seeking_talent">Looking for Talent</label>
         {{ form.seeking_talent(placeholder='Venue', autofocus = true) }}
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="seeking_description">Seeking Description</label>
        {{ form.seeking_description(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='Description', autofocus = true) }}
   </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Create Venue" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
</form>
```

Whenever I try to create a venue the `if newForm.validate_on_Submit()` is not fulfilled and the else is executed

Comment: What's in `newForm.errors`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb No error is shown

Answer (score 0):

try passing **request.form** into form init

```
newForm = VenueForm(**request.form)
```